# Automating Pivots with Variable Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I am trying to automate a simple pivot table using pandas that can accommodate missing columns. The source data is a .csv export and contains fairly uniform data; however, sometimes one or more columns are missing from the source data. Therefore, I am trying to create a program to handle the variable column headers and pivot the data accordingly.

So, if all the columns are present in the source data then the full pivot is completed (seen below) and the program will stop.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)


Overview = df[['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4']]

Overview = Overview.pivot_table(index="Column1",
                                             values = ['Column2','Column3','Column4'],
                                             aggfunc = {'Column2':len,'Column3':np.sum, 'Column4':np.sum})
```

If one column is missing then a limited pivot is completed (below). The program will stop here.

```
Overview = df[['Column1','Column2','Column3']]

Overview = Overview.pivot_table(index="Column1",
                                              values = ['Column2','Column3'],
                                              aggfunc = {'Column2':len,'Column3':np.sum})
```

If most columns are missing then this final pivot is completed and the program ends.

```
Overview = df[['Column1','Column2']]

Overview = Overview.pivot_table(index="Column1",
                                              values = ['Column2'],
                                              aggfunc = {'Column2':len})
```

Comment: When you say the columns are missing, do you mean that they're omitted from the actual .csv? Or do they have null values? Please clarify

Comment: The missing columns are omitted from the .csv file.

Comment: If you could provide some of the data that you're working with that could be helpful...Are you defining which columns you want to pivot? Are they supposed to be standard across csv's? Need more information...

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, atlas. Unfortunately, the content is legally privileged information so I cannot provide the data. That is why I created such a simplified version of the program. To answer your question, yes, the columns are standardized across the csv’s.  
I am trying to create a program that can identify what columns are available in the current csv and will create the appropriate pivot to utilize the maximum amount of data. So if Column1, Column2 and Column3 are available in the .csv the program will run the second piece of code (outlined above) and ignore the others. Thx

Comment: Hmm I'm working on it. I'm stuck at creating a dictionary for the `aggfunc` based on which columns are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long-winded solution...

Please note that I am assuming 'Column1' will always be present in the .csv files. Your examples all showed that 'Column1' would be available.

```
#Define which columns you want to check for (in this case, all of them)
list_of_columns = ['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4']

lst = [] #Create dummy list
dels = [] #Create dummy list for deleting dictionary key/value pairs later

for l in list_of_columns:
    if l in df.columns.tolist():
        lst.append(l) 
    else:
        dels.append(l) 

#Define all functions possible for certain columns outside of index
d = {'Column2':len,'Column3':np.sum, 'Column4':np.sum}

#Remove key/value pairs from dictionary if a column is not present in .csv
for i in dels:
    del dels[i]

Overview = df[lst].pivot_table(index="Column1",
                   values = [lst[1:],
                   aggfunc = d)
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to define the code as a function as well.

Comment: I ran into this error. "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" for "del dels[i]"

Comment: I apologize... It should have been `del d[i]`. I referenced the list instead of the dictionary.

Comment: No problem - feel free to wrap it into a function if you're going to using it a lot.